# Is it the constructor of a class that follows the new keyword in java?

Tags: java, class, new-operator, instantiation

when we write something like

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Do we actually call the constructor defined in Scanner class with new Scanner(System.in)? 
If the answer is yes then how is it possible to access the constructor which is a special type of method without creating an instance. 
If the answer is no then why does it always have to have a name of a constructor?

Comment: who said constructor is a method ?

Comment: It's yes. And it's possible because that's the whole point of a constructor: creating an instance. Constructors would be useless if you needed an instance to be able to call them. Constructors are not methods, and are not invoked like methods. They're constructors. They're invoked using the new keyword, and are used to create an instance of the class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: new is followed by the Constructor (which may be overloaded based on input parameters) and once it is executed the object on the heap is initilized as per constructor implementation. Now you can invoke the accessible methods. Constructor and methods are different, constructor is not a method.

Comment: @nits.kk http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/constructors.html

Comment: A blog is not official source , better refer oracle docs and jls. I qoute from JLS "Constructor declarations are not members. They are never inherited and therefore are not subject to hiding or overriding". refer JLS https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8

Comment: In the blog you mentioned it has been mentioned it is a special method. Actually object on heap is created when JVM envounters new keyword and by the name of the constructor JVM knows the type. Now after the object is created constructor execution takes place where object state is initilized. This can be verified creating a class and including the finalize method and throwing an exception from its constructor, use new keyword to create its object, exception will be thrown, call system.gc to influence GC to happen and put a print statement in finalize method, you will have a live object.

Comment: @nits.kk I know it is mentioned as a special method. This is exactly what I said in my question. That method is a special type of method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we actually call the constructor defined in Scanner class with new Scanner(System.in)?

yes.

> If the answer is yes then how is it possible to access the constructor which is a special type of method without creating an instance.

You can copy the bytecode and create a method with the same code to do the same thing.
However, you can't call the constructor by normal means as a method.

A Constructor is like a Method in some ways, however it is different in the sense it is only called to initialise a new object and is not used to be called directly.

Comment: *"A Constructor is like a Method in **a few** ways"*. Common: access modifiers, parameters, exceptions. Differences: other modifiers, generic specifier, return value, how to invoke, inheritance, reflection, ...

Comment: Thanks peter my guy. I dont understand the thumbs down though to my question from those shadow-less faceless people who disliked it for no apparent reason

Comment: @Andreas the signature of a constructor always has a return type of "V" for void. ;)